# Contact form - user's name and email coming through as 'unknown'

Tags: php, email, gmail, contact-form

Apologies, I am aware this question has been asked quite afew times already on this site, however I have tried to implement what others have suggested but with no luck.

Same as everyone else I have a very simple contact form and for the sake of this example I have stripped the PHP coding to the bare minimum so it is simpler to look at.

It works fine in the sense I receive the email in GMail with the message, however the email and name the user filled-in never shows up.

- I have tried taking '\r' out and just leaving '\n\
- Other methods have either resulted in the email going to junk or the same (coming through as unknown).

  ```
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="email">Email address</label>
                                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="message">Message</label>
                              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn tf-btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                      </form>
  ```

PHP Code

```
<?php

$to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = 'RE: RMW interest';

$headers .= 'From:' .$name. " ".'<'.$email.'>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Thank you for contacting us, we will respond shortly!";

?>
```

I would be most grateful if someone could shed some light on this particular case please.

Many thanks

Comment: You're not using `$name` anywhere in your code -- where are you expecting it to appear?

Comment: oops sorry I stripped down the php code a bit too much, I have edited the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in HTML code not in PHP,

You forgot to name the inputs, so when you call [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) in contact.php file you will found just the message.

in contact.php when you write `print_r($_POST);`
the output will be

```
Array ( [message] => message)
```

Now you know the problem so you want to name all inputs.

```
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
...
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
...
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn tf-btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

So the output now is

```
Array ( [email] => test@test.test [name] => test [message] => test message [submit] => )
```

And here i named the button because you can check if the button clicked send the message.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //your code here
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I will give this a go.

Comment: Much appreciated, it worked like a charm :). Also thank you for explaining where it went wrong too, I shall remember your words of wisdom. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome @Jeoul, It's a pleasure to hear that from you :)